# How to search OpenStreetMap for tags?

Tags: search, url, syntax, geolocation, openstreetmap

How can I have e.g. all [highway speed cameras](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:highway%3Dspeed_camera) displayed on the map, i.e. what is the URL syntax to search [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org) for certain **tags**?

Comment: You should move your question over at gis.se or webapps.se. I doubt that many people here are doing any mapping. But for what it's worth, since I was able to censor out from OSM a road _bridge_ (which never existed but still appears on _all_ maps, including but not limited to google's), other people may be able to wipe a highway speed camera off the map if they really want to.

Comment: @pizdelect: GIS would be worth a shot. How do I move a question and will the bounty be preserved?

Comment: This question very off topic.  It also lacks some basic research prior to posting.  [OpenStreetMap is a free, editable map of the whole world that is being built by volunteers largely from scratch and released with an open-content license.](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/About_OpenStreetMap).  There is also a more detailed [contributors page](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Contributors).  WRT redacting information, that's largely the same as any open source project.  Changes can be made by contributors, others are usually free to revert changes if the law of their country allows.

Comment: Scope of question has been reduced to make it more focused and the bounty has been awarded to stefanct's nice answer

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to be related to Unix & Linux at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is really offtopic here, but since you pledged some bounty you deserve at least a short answer. :)

I don't think there is a way to search for tags on osm.org - it is basically only one frontend of many to view the data. It is not completely clear what you want to do with the replied data, but I presume [this](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/WGV) would suit you. The Overpass API is the most common way to query the database for specific data and this website is one interface using it (but you could do the same on a command line against a local dump of the database for example).

The data is similarly maintained as wikipedia: volunteers that get data from the ground by surveying, using open government data and other suitably licensed sources (e.g., Bing aerial photos have been provided).

Like on wikipedia every with an account can edit the data - thus there exist similar problems like individuals and corporations trying to push their interests. I know of various incidents regarding Israel and China military installations, private owners of forests with paths that they did not want to be on any map etc. but in general vandalism and especially simply bad volunteers are bigger problems to OSM's data quality  than governments.

Comment: It [works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBBOY.jpg)! But I still wonder if there is any way to do this directly from OSM via the URL syntax

Comment: I believe the website you linked uses `nominatim` as a frontend. Here is the API documentation: https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Search/

Comment: This might actually be the solution I was originally looking for! But I don't quite understand the documentation on their URL syntax. How do I combine `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/<query>?<params>` with `highway=speed_camera`?

Comment: nominatim is (very) focused on addresses and does not support arbitrary searches. But overpassturbo does have a GET API. I am not sure if/where good documentation can be found. As of now this might be the best to help you: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/Development#URL_Parameters Since this question is offtopic please open up a new question on the appropriate SE subsite if you have further questions.